# In Java can I reference an object made in one class in another?

Tags: java, oop

I have 3 classes:

- Main
- Commands
- Team

Inside **Main** I am creating an object which uses a method inside **Team**:

```
Team humanTeam = new Team("Humans");
Team monsterTeam = new Team("Monsters");
```

Is it possible to include that inside **Commands** without recreating an object? or is it okay to recreate it?

*Example of humanTeam being called inside Commands:*

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        Player p = (Player)sender;
                if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("joinhuman")){
                Team.addPlayer(humanTeam, p); //This line.
                p.sendMessage("You just joined the human team!");
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Definitely, you can pass object references between objects.  In generally you do not want to create a new object just to invoke a method of the object, since that will cause you to reference different instance variable values.

Comment: Normally, one would make the `addPlayer` method be an instance method of Team, so you would invoke it as `humanTeam.addPlayer(p);`.  The way you have written things it must be a `static` method of Team.

Comment: In general, in your code above, there should only be one place where a particular Team is created (though "Humans" can be created in one place and "Monsters" in another).  If you want to pass the Teams from one class to another you can pass them in the constructor for the new class, or you can implement a `setHumanTeam` and a `setMonsterTeam` method in Commands.java and invoke those methods from Main.java after you create the Commands instance.

Comment: Is it worth me actually creating humanTeam and monsterTeam inside my Team Class. That could be neater and easier to read?

Comment: Probably that would not be a good idea.  It's best to do all your setup in one place, in a clear, easily analyzed sequence, vs spreading it about.  But it's a judgment call.

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance one might suggest to make `addPlayer` a static method, but that might not be an ideal design in this scenario.  Because `Team` isn't a static concept, but rather an instance concept:

```
Team humanTeam = new Team("Humans");
Team monsterTeam = new Team("Monsters");
```

You have two specific *instances* of `Team`, as opposed to one generic *concept* of `Team`.  So you're going to want to add a player to an *instance* of `Team` rather than to the *concept* of `Team`.  It's really just semantics, but I think makes for a cleaner implementation of separating instance concepts from static concepts.

So what you're likely looking to do (in what appears to be a Minecraft Bukkit plugin) is track your `Team` instances in some meaningful way so that various events and objects in your plugin can access those stored instances.  A database is probably best for this, particularly if you want to persist the concept of teams between game re-starts.  If that's not a requirement, then you could take your instances of `Team`s and store them statically.  Given the hard-coded lines above, it seems reasonable that you could just as daily hard-code them on the `Team` class:

```
class Team {
    private static humanTeam;
    private static monsterTeam;

    // initialize them inline or in the static initializer

    public static Team getHumanTeam {
        return humanTeam;
    }

    public static Team getMonsterTeam {
        return monsterTeam;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

You can refer to these "get" methods in this case as "factory methods" for your teams.  If you were to add more kinds of teams over time then you might make a more general "factory" which accepts some kind of team identifier (a string for the team's name for example).  Those teams might also be stored as a dictionary of team names and instances.  Ultimately what you're doing in this setup is keeping the management of "teams" encapsulated to the `Team` class.  As the overall logic grows, you might separate the concerns even further by extracting a `TeamMeneger` class just to hold the logic of managing teams.

Now any class in your game can statically reference those specific instances:

```
Team.getHumanTeam().addPlayer(p);
```

(Another important benefit of this is that you can mock your factory methods in unit tests, and you'll find in general that instance logic is a lot easier to unit test than static logic.)

Comment: Hi David, if you have a spare 10 minutes would you mind coming into a chat with me?

Answer (score 0):

If your Commands have dependency on Team class you can do something like this.

```
    public class Commands{
    private Team humanTeam;
    private Team monsterTeam;

    public Team getHumanTeam() {
        return humanTeam;
    }

    public void setHumanTeam(Team humanTeam) {
        this.humanTeam = humanTeam;
    }

    public Team getMonsterTeam() {
        return monsterTeam;
    }

    public void setMonsterTeam(Team monsterTeam) {
        this.monsterTeam = monsterTeam;
    }
 }
```

Now when you create Team object like this

```
Team humanTeam = new Team("Humans");
Team monsterTeam = new Team("Monsters");
```

just set the Objects to the Commands class properties like this

```
Commands commands = new Commands();
commands.setHumanTeam(humanTeam);
commands.setMonsterTeam (monsterTeam );
```

Now you can use them to manipulate the Commands class.